# ERROR Error: Error trying to diff '[{"opened":"2", "closed":"2", "assigned":"2", "reopen":"1" }]'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed

Tags: angular

error isERROR Error: Error trying to diff '[{"opened":"2", "closed":"2", "assigned":"2", "reopen":"1
}]'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed

1.I get the data in console.but i didn't itrate the data in browser
2.Im using *ngFor here for itrate the data.

and this is my code.

**Html**

```
                    <div class="row">
                    <div class="container-fluid">



                     <div class="col-xl-2 col-lg-4 col-md-4 pl-2 pr-2 mb-2 text-left">  
                     <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary pp mb-1" style="height:70px;width:190px" data-container="body" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" data-content="Captured higher Email pref optin of 60K than normal 35K, Store sales higher than normal, Myclient captured more product preferences of 30K than normal 20K">
                     <div class="col-md-2">
                     <span *ngFor="let post of results">{{post.opened}}</span><br>
                     <i class="fa fa-user mr-2"></i>Opened

                   </div>
                   </button>
                   </div>
```

This is my component.ts

```
   import { Component, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
import { AppSettings } from '../../../app.settings';
import { Settings } from '../../../app.settings.model';
import { BatchService } from '../../config/batchnew/batch.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-info-panels',
  templateUrl: './info-panels.component.html',
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class InfoPanelsComponent {



  results:any = [];





   constructor (public appSettings:AppSettings,private router: Router,private dataservice:BatchService) 
   {
    this.settings = this.appSettings.settings;
   }



   ngOnInit() {
    this.dataservice.getData().subscribe((readdata)=>{this.results=readdata,console.log(this.results)})

  jQuery('.tt').tooltip();
  jQuery('.pp').popover();
}  
public previousShowMenuOption:boolean;
public previousMenuOption:string;
public previousMenuTypeOption:string;
public settings: Settings;


public checkAppSettingsChanges(){
  if(this.previousShowMenuOption != this.settings.theme.showMenu ||
    this.previousMenuOption != this.settings.theme.menu ||
    this.previousMenuTypeOption != this.settings.theme.menuType){
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}

public initPreviousSettings(){
  this.previousShowMenuOption = this.settings.theme.showMenu;
  this.previousMenuOption = this.settings.theme.menu;
  this.previousMenuTypeOption = this.settings.theme.menuType;
}






}
```

This is my service code.

```
 import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

import { Batch } from './batch.model';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/observable';


const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
};

@Injectable()
export class BatchService {

  constructor(private http:HttpClient) {}


  private Dashbord=' https://je2ngjw0w0.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev/dashboard';



  public  getData():Observable<any[]>
  {
     return this.http.get<any[]>(this.Dashbord);
  }
```

Comment: You are showing same code in your component and in service. Please edit it.

Comment: '[{"opened":"2", "closed":"2", "assigned":"2", "reopen":"1 }]'.

Your json data is wrong see last one reopen key value not properly "" closed.just edit and try one more time

Comment: I edited but giving same error

Comment: Show your console.log(this.results) value. Then only proceed something.

Comment: [{"opened":"2", "closed":"2", "assigned":"2", "reopen":"1"
}].................This is my console value